# Linux, execute operations that needs superuser privilege with Electronjs - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, electron

Sorry but I don't know much about linux and i always developped in other environments, I made a cross-platform application with **electronJS** and i need to create a directory with that code

```
 let staticPath = "/opt/pcapp/resources/monitor";
 if (!fs.existsSync(staticPath)) {
       fs.mkdirSync(staticPath);
 }
```

In Windows and Mac it works like a charm but on Linux - Ubuntu I installed the app and i get this error due to the required superuser rights.
[image]

**The users who are going to deal with the application will not have superuser privilege**

Now i would like to know if there is a way to grant permission to create, update and delete some files and directory in the Application working directory */opt/pcapp/resources/monitor* without **SUDO** or other stuff.

Comment: _if any application can elevate itself to certain privilege not allowed_, that is security issue. An application must run under right privilege to do jobs, i.e sudo as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options I can think of.

1) ACLs which will take a bit of a learning curve.
2) Simple permissions and groups which can be done quite easily.

I created a group mygroup and added a couple of users to it.

```
# groupadd mygroup
# usermod -G mygroup user1
# usermod -G mygroup user2
```

I then change the permissions and group on the folder you want the users to have access to:

```
# chmod 02770  /opt/pcapp/resourcees/monitor
# chgrp mygroup /opt/pcapp/resourcees/monitor
```

You should now see the following:

```
# ls -ld /opt/pcapp/resourcees/monitor
drwxrws---. 4 root mygroup 4096 Dec  6 17:23 /opt/pcapp/resourcees/monitor
```

Now any **new** file created in the folder will have a group mygroup. You will have to change existing files and folders.

As user2

```
$ touch /opt/pcapp/resourcees/monitor/testfile1
$ ls -ld /opt/pcapp/resourcees/monitor/testfile1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user2 mygroup 0 Dec  6 17:29 /opt/pcapp/resourcees/monitor/testfile1
```

As user1

```
$ rm -v /opt/pcapp/resourcees/monitor/testfile1 
removed ‘/opt/pcapp/resourcees/monitor/testfile1’
```

If this isn't granular enough, read about Linux ACLs.

Hope this helps.